# fish shell --- how to simulate or implement a hash table, associative array, or key-value store

Tags: dictionary, associative-array, fish

I am migrating from `ksh` to `fish`.  I am finding that I miss the ability to define an associative array, hash table, dictionary, or whatever you wish to call it.  Some cases can be simulated as in

`set dictionary$key $value
eval echo '$'dictionary$key`

But this approach is heavily limited; for example, `$key` may contain only letters, numbers, and underscores.

I understand that the `fish` approach is to find an external command when one is available, but I am a little reluctant to store key-value information in the filesystem, even in `/run/user/<uid>`, because that limits me to "universal" scope.

How do `fish` programmers work around the lack of a key-value store?  Is there some simple approach that I am just missing?

Here's an example of the sort of problem I would like to solve: I would like to modify the `fish_prompt` function so that certain directories print not using `prompt_pwd` but using special abbreviations.  I could certainly do this with a `switch` command, but I would much rather have a universal dictionary so I can just look up a directory and see if it has an abbreviation.  Then I could change the abbreviations using `set` instead of having to edit a function.

Comment: This has been requested in issue #390 (https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/390). Until such time as that is implemented there are various ways to hack around the lack using solutions like the one provided by faho below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can store the keys in one variable and values in the other, and then use something like

```
if set -l index (contains -i -- foo $keys) # `set` won't modify $status, so this succeeds if `contains` succeeds
    echo $values[$index]
end
```

to retrieve the corresponding value.

Other possibilities include alternating between key and value in one variable, though iterating through this is a pain, especially when you try to do it only with builtins. Or you could use a separator character and store a key-value pair as one element, though this won't work for directories because variables cannot contain \0 (which is the only possible separator for paths).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I implemented the alternative solution mentioned by @faho

I'm using '__' as seperator.

```
function set_field --argument-names dict key value
    set -g $dict'__'$key $value
end

function get_field --argument-names dict key
    eval echo \$$dict'__'$key
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use a single variable with paired key/values, it's possible but as @faho mentioned, it is more complicated. Here's how you could do it:

```fish
function dict_keys -d "Print keys from a key/value paired list"
    for idx in (seq 1 2 (count $argv))
        echo $argv[$idx]
    end
end

function dict_values -d "Print values from a key/value paired list"
    for idx in (seq 2 2 (count $argv))
        echo $argv[$idx]
    end
end

function dict_get -a key -d "Get the value associated with a key in a k/v paired list"
    test (count $argv) -gt 2 || return 1
    set -l keyseq (seq 2 2 (count $argv))
    # we can't simply use `contains` because it won't distinguish keys from values
    for idx in $keyseq
        if test $key = $argv[$idx]
            echo $argv[(math $idx + 1)]
            return
        end
    end
    return 1
end
```

Then you could use these functions like this:

```fish
$ set -l mydict \
         yellow banana \
         red cherry \
         green grape \
         blue berry

$ dict_keys $mydict
yellow
red
green
blue


$ dict_values $mydict
banana
cherry
grape
berry

$ dict_get blue $mydict
berry

$ dict_get purple $mydict || echo "not found"
not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally needed this for an application, and I'm not super comfortable with fish builtins, so here is an implementation in Lua: https://gist.github.com/nrnrnr/b302db5c59c600dd75c38d460423cc3d.  This code uses the alternating key/value representation:

```
key1 value1 key2 value2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@faho's answer got me thinking about this and there are a few this I wanted to add.

At first I wrote a small set of fish functions (A sort of library, if you will) that dealt with serialization, you would call a `dict` function with a key name, an operation (`get`, `set`, `add` or `del`) and it would use global variables to keep track of keys and their values. Works fine for flat `hash`es/`dict`s/objects, but felt somewhat unsatisfactory.

Then I realized I could use something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to (de-)serialize JSON. That would also make it a lot easier to deal with nesting, plus that allows having different `dict`s which use the same name for a `key` without any issues. It also separates "dealing-with-environment-variables" and "dealing-with-dicts(/hashes/etc)", which seems like a good idea. I'll focus on `jq` here, but the same applies to `yq` or pretty much anything, the core point is: Serialize data before storing, de-serialize when reading, and use some tool to work with such data.

I then proceeded to rewrite my functions using `jq`. however I soon realized it was easier to just use `jq` without any functions. To summarize the workfolow, let's consider OP's scenario and imagine we want to use abbreviations for User folders, or even better, we wanna use icons for such folders. To do that, let's assume we use [Nerdfonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) and have their icons availabe. A quick search for folders on [Nerdfont's cheat sheet](https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet) show we only have folder icons for the home folder (`f74b`), downloads(`f74c`) and images(`f74e`), so I'll use Material Design Icon's "File document box" (`f719`) for documents, and Material Design Icon's "Video" (`fa66`) for Videos.

So our Codepoints are:

- User folder: `\uf74b`
- Downloads `\uf74c`
- Images: `\uf74e`
- Documents: `\uf719`
- Videos: `\ufa66`

So our JSON is:

```
{"~":"\uf74b","downloads":"\uf74c","images":"\uf74e","documents":"\uf719","videos":"\ufa66"}
```

I kept it in a single line for a reason which will become obvious now. Let's visualize this using `jq`:

```
echo '{"~":"\uf74b","downloads":"\uf74c","images":"\uf74e","documents":"\uf719","videos":"\ufa66"}' | jq                                    
```

For completeness sake, here's how it looks with Nerdfonts installed:

[image: image of json with icons]

Now let's store this as a variable:

```
set -g FOLDER_ICONS (echo '{"~":"\uf74b","downloads":"\uf74c","images":"\uf74e","documents":"\uf719","videos":"\ufa66"}' | jq -c)
```

`jq -c` interprets JSON and outputs JSON in a `compact` structure, i.e., a single line. Ideal for storing variables.

If you need to edit something you can use `jq`, lat's say you want to change the abbreviation for documents to "doc" instead of an icon. Just do:

```
set -g FOLDER_ICONS (echo $FOLDER_ICONS | jq -c '.["documents"]="doc"')
```

The `echo` part is for reading a variable, and the `set -g` is for updating the variable. So those can be ignored if you're not working with variables.

As for retrieving values, `jq` also does that, obviously. Let's say you want to get the abbreviation for the `documents` folder, you can simply do:

```
echo $FOLDER_ICONS | jq -r '.["documents"]'
```

It will return `doc`. If you leave out the `-r` it will return `"doc"`, with quotes, since strings are quoted in JSON.

You can also remove keys pretty easily, i.e.:

```
set -g FOLDER_ICONS (echo $FOLDER_ICONS | jq -c 'del(."documents")')
```

will `set` the variable `FOLDER_ICONS` to the result of reading it and passing its contents to `jq -c 'del(."documents")'`, which tels `jq` to delete the key `"documents"` and output a compact representation of the JSON, i.e. a single line.

Everything I tried worked perfectly fine with nested JSON objects, so it seems like a pretty good solution. It's just a matter of keeping the operations in mind:

```
reading  .["key"]
writing  .["key"]="value"
deleting del(."key")
```

`jq` also has many other nice features, I wanted to showcase a bit of them so I tried looking for stuff that might be nice to include here. One of the things I use `jq` for is dealing with wayland stuff, especially `swaymsg -t get_tree`, which I've just ran and, with a mere 4 workspaces with a single window in each, outputs a 706-line JSON from hell (Was 929 when I wrote this, 6 windows across 5 workspaces, later I closed 2 windows I was done with so I came back here and re-ran the command to share the lowest possible value).

To give a more complex example of how `jq` might be used, here's parsing the `swaymsg -t get_tree`:

```
swaymsg -t get_tree | jq -C '{"id": .id, "type": .type, "name": .name, "nodes": (.nodes | map(.nodes) | flatten | map({"id": .id, "type": .type, "name": .name, "nodes": (.nodes | map(.nodes) | flatten | map({"id": .id, "type": .type, "name": .name}))}))}'
```

This will give you a tree with only `id`, `type`, `name` and `nodes`, where `nodes` is an array of objects, each consisting of the `id`, `type`, `name` and `nodes` of the children, with the children `nodes` also being an array of objects, now consisting of only `id`, `type` and `name`. In my case, it returned:

```
{                                                          
  "id": 1,                                                 
  "type": "root",                                          
  "name": "root",                                          
  "nodes": [                                               
    {                                                      
      "id": 2147483646,                                    
      "type": "workspace",                                 
      "name": "__i3_scratch",                              
      "nodes": []                                          
    },                                                     
    {                                                      
      "id": 184,                                           
      "type": "workspace",                                 
      "name": "1",                                         
      "nodes": []                                          
    },                                                     
    {                                                      
      "id": 145,                                           
      "type": "workspace",                                 
      "name": "2",                                                                                                     
      "nodes": []                                          
    },                                                     
    {                                                      
      "id": 172,                                           
      "type": "workspace",                                 
      "name": "3",                                         
      "nodes": [                                           
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          "id": 173,                                       
          "type": "con",                                   
          "name": "Untitled-4 - Code - OSS"                                                                    
        }                                                  
      ]                                                    
    },                                                     
    {                                                      
      "id": 5,                                             
      "type": "workspace",                                 
      "name": "4",                                         
      "nodes": []                                          
    }                                                      
  ]                                                        
}
```

You can also easily make a flattened version of that with `jq` by slightly changing the command:

```
swaymsg -t get_tree | jq -C '[{"id": .id, "type": .type, "name": .name}, (.nodes | map(.nodes) | flatten | map([{"id": .id, "type": .type, "name": .name}, (.nodes | map(.nodes) | flatten | map({"id": .id, "type": .type, "name": .name}))]))] | flatten'
```

Now instead of having a key `nodes`, the child nodes are also in the parent's array, flattened, in my case:

```
[                                                          
  {                                                        
    "id": 1,                                               
    "type": "root",                                        
    "name": "root"                                         
  },                                                       
  {                                                        
    "id": 2147483646,                                      
    "type": "workspace",                                   
    "name": "__i3_scratch"                                 
  },                                                       
  {                                                        
    "id": 184,                                             
    "type": "workspace",                                   
    "name": "1"                                            
  },                                                       
  {                                                        
    "id": 145,                                             
    "type": "workspace",                                   
    "name": "2"                                            
  },                                                       
  {                                                        
    "id": 172,                                             
    "type": "workspace",                                   
    "name": "3"                                            
  },                                                       
  {                                                        
    "id": 173,                                             
    "type": "con",                                         
    "name": "Untitled-4 - Code - OSS"                                                                          
  },                                                       
  {                                                        
    "id": 5,                                               
    "type": "workspace",                                   
    "name": "4"                                            
  }                                                        
]
```

It's pretty nifty, not limited to environment variables, and solves pretty much every problem I can think of. The only con is verbosity, so it may be a good idea to write a few fish functions for dealing with that, but that's beyond the scope here, as I'm focusing on a general approach to (de-)serialization of key-value mappings (i.e., `dict`s, `hash`es, `object`s etc), which can be (also) used with environment variables. For reference, a good starting point if dealing with variables might be:

```
function dict
  switch $argv[2]
    case write
      read data
      set -xg $argv[1] "$data"
    case read, '*'
      echo $$argv[1]
  end
end
```

This simply deals with reading and writing to a variable, the only reason it's worth sharing is, first, that it allows piping something to a variable, and second, that it sets a starting point to make something more complex, i.e. automatically piping the `echo`ed value to `jq`, or adding an `add` operation or whatever.

There's also the option of writing a script to deal with that, instead of using `jq`. Ruby's `Marshal` and `to_yaml` seems like interesting options, since I like ruby, but each person has their own preferences. For Python, `pickle`, `pyyaml` and `json` seem worth mentioning.

It's worth mentioning I'm not affiliated to `jq` in any way, never contributed nor even posted anything on issues or whatever, I just use it, and as someone who used to write scripts whenever I had to deal with JSON or YAML, it was quite surprising when I realized how powerful it was.